# TFS suits for small sized projects?

Tags: tfs

My team has small sized projects - lasting for 2-4 weeks at the most.  Is it a good idea to opt for TFS scrum for project management for such a team work ? When project is done, the team starts with a new project .  I am not sure whether i should go for TFS or not.

Also, as the team deals with many projects, again it is a problem to have same templates in all the projects and keep track accross projects. I can write cross-project queries though. Still customizing rights and delivering templates acrross projects is a tough job. Also, cross-quering becomes difficult, when a past project has a diffrent template installed.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about programming methodology and therefore fits better programming.stackexchange.com site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use TFS to manage even my one-man projects.  If you want to have version control, work tracking, and/or automated build, TFS can be a good choice regardless of team/project size.

If your projects follow the same process, then I'd suggest having them all part of the same Team Project using the same process template.  If they use different processes, then it probably makes sense to split them up into multiple Team Projects to support this.